# How to downgrade python from 3.10 to 3.9 on Ubuntu, WSL

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I need to downgrade python for a project. Unable to downgrade from 3.10 to 3.9 on Ubuntu, Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Comment: You don't need to downgrade - you can have multiple Python installations living next to each other quite happily. Just install 3.9 and make sure to specify it when running your programs.

Comment: @MattDMo How to specify python version when using a pip3 command?

Comment: pip can't install another Python version. You either need to download and install from the Python website (not recommended: the installation may conflict with the system version), use something like Conda, or (my preferred tool) use pyenv to install any Python version you like, without any conflicts.

Comment: Or, depending on what you're using to install, then you can use `python3.9 -m pip` instead.

Answer (score 13):

Try the following steps
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa

apt list | grep python3.9

sudo apt install python3.9

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 1

sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

Comment: I had to run `sudo apt-get install python3.9-distutils` after all for pip to get running on python3.9.